# Variable scope inside lambda

Tags: python, scope

Why does this code print "d, d, d, d", and not "a, b, c, d"? How can I modify it to print "a, b, c, d"?

```
cons = []
for i in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']: 
    cons.append(lambda: i)  
print ', '.join([fn() for fn in cons])
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760688/use-value-of-variable-in-lambda-expression?rq=1

Comment: I'm not sure that's an exact duplicate, actually--this isn't asking how to change the behavior, it's asking why the behavior is that way in the first place.

Comment: I agree with Kyle, for what it's worth, and attempted to answer in that vein.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oddly enough, this is not a variable *scope* problem, but a quesiton of the semantics of python's `for` loop (and of python's variables).

As you expect, `i` inside your lambda correctly refers to the variable `i` in the nearest enclosing scope.  So far, so good.

However, you are expecting this to mean the following happens:

```
for each value in the list ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']: 
    instantiate a new variable, i, pointing to the current list member
    instantiate a new anonymous function, which returns i
    append this function to cons
```

What actually happens is this:

```
instantiate a new variable i
for each value in the list ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']: 
    make i refer to the current list member
    instantiate a new anonymous function, which returns i
    append this function to cons
```

Thus, your code is appending the *same* variable `i` to the list four times -- and by the time the loop exits, `i` has a value of `'d'`.

Note that if python functions took and returned the value of their arguments / return values by *value*, you would not notice this, as the *contents* of `i` would be copied on each call to `append` (or, for that matter, on each return from the anonymous function created with `lambda`).  In actuality, however, python variables are always *references* to a particular object-- and thus your four copies of `i` all refer to `'d'` by then end of your loop.

Comment: You can verify this by printing `i` after exiting the loop. You can also verify that all four lambda functions are technically different functions by printing `cons` and comparing the ID's.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a closure, the variables that are "closed over" by your lambdas (in this case, `i`) are bound by name, not value. Therefore, whenever you call your lambdas, they'll use the last value of 'i'.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the simple fix you need to make that work:

```
cons = []
for i in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']: 
    cons.append(lambda i=i: i)  
print ', '.join([fn() for fn in cons])
```

Answer (score 0):

'Erics' answer as a comprehension :

```
 cons =[lambda i= i:i for i in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]   
 print ', '.join([fn() for fn in cons])
```